# find the vector a {1, 1, 1} length of the projection in the vector b

Tags: vectors, projection

I need to find the vector a {1, 1, 1} length of the projection in the vector b

Given:
vector b with the OX axis forms a 30 degree angle

vector b with the OZ axis forms a 60 degree angle

What formulas do I need to use?

[image]

Comment: So if we start by asking, "What can the vector $\vec{b}$ look like?", it's not difficult to see that there are (at least) two options for it. The $y$-component of $\vec{b}$ can be either positive or negative, and we don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ||a|| \,||b|| \,\cos \theta$

Say $\vec {b} = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$

Unit vector in the direction of $x-$axis $= (1,0,0)$

So $(b_1, b_2, b_3) \cdot (1,0,0) = \sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2} \, \cos 30^0$

Or the direction angle of a vector with $x$ and $z$ axis is simply given by

$\cos \alpha = \frac{b_1}{\sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2}}, \cos \gamma = \frac{b_3}{\sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2}} \,$ respectively.

That gives you two equations.

Solve for $b_1, b_2, b_3$ in terms of one of them and divide by magnitude to get the unit vector in the direction of $\vec{b}$.

Now dot product of $(1,1,1)$ with unit vector in the direction of $\vec{b}$ will give the projection of $(1,1,1)$ in vector $\vec{b}$.

Comment: How to solve for b1,b2,b3 in terms of one of them and divide by magnitude to get the unit vector in the direction of vector b?

Comment: i got that cos α is 1 and cos γ  is 0. Root from square (b1+b2+b3) multiplied by cos 30 = root 3/ 2. The length of the vector a is a root of 3. What formulas do I need to use next to solve this?

Comment: the angles are correct. What we know that  Vector a is (1, 1 , 1) , cos α is 1, cos y is 0. Root from square (b1+b2+b3) multiplied by cos 30 = root 3/ 2. I get 1/2 and root of3/2. But dont understand how you got vector b coordinates (root of 3b3, 0, and b3) ? And cos^2 of 30 and cos^2 60 cant be = 1, because the formulas is that cos^2 of α + cos^2 of  b + cos^2  γ = 1, but we dont have cos^2 b. Or I am wrong?

Comment: so the answer is 1/2 and root 3/2?  What next then?

Comment: dot product of $(1,1,1)$ and unit vector in the direction of $b$ which is $(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2})$ will give you the length of projection of $(1,1,1)$ in vector $b$.

Comment: this is the most hard step. Is there are any formulas I need to use?

Comment: so all the projection length is (the root of 3+1)/2. But the question I needed fo find the vector's a {1, 1, 1} length of the projection in the vector b . So the answer is (the root of 3+1)/2?

Comment: yes that is the length of the projection.

Comment: So if i understood right that the length of vector a in the projection is itself projection's length (the root of 3+1)/2)?

Comment: thank you so much!